# What do the sk_buff functions skb_network_header() and skb_mac_header() do?

Tags: c, linux, networking, kernel

Do they return the IP header and mac header respectively? I'm a little confused because just looking at the implementation, they are returning pointers that are skb->head + skb->network_header and the like. Why not just get the network header by doing skb->network_header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 versions of [skb_network_header()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h?v=3.0#L1263)

```
#ifdef NET_SKBUFF_DATA_USES_OFFSET

static inline unsigned char *skb_network_header(const struct sk_buff )
{
        return skb->head + skb->network_header;
}
#else
static inline unsigned char *skb_network_header(const struct sk_buff *skb)
{
     return skb->network_header;
}
```

Basically, if NET_SKBUFF_DATA_USES_OFFSET is in effect (e.g. for 64 bit architectures), `.network_header` is an offset from the start.

Comment: Gah - you beat me to it!  +1

Comment: Oh I see, thanks, I didn't see the other definition. This makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking at the kernel source code [somewhere like this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h?v=3.0#L1282)

If we cut out some of the code, I think it becomes something like this:

```
#ifdef NET_SKBUFF_DATA_USES_OFFSET
static inline unsigned char *skb_network_header(const struct sk_buff *skb)
{
        return skb->head + skb->network_header;
}

static inline unsigned char *skb_mac_header(const struct sk_buff *skb)
{
        return skb->head + skb->mac_header;
}

#else /* NET_SKBUFF_DATA_USES_OFFSET */

static inline unsigned char *skb_network_header(const struct sk_buff *skb)
{
        return skb->network_header;
}

static inline unsigned char *skb_mac_header(const struct sk_buff *skb)
{
        return skb->mac_header;
}

#endif /* NET_SKBUFF_DATA_USES_OFFSET */
```